# Getting to ServletContext from ApplicationListener

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-domino

We are using an ApplicationListener to load some timer libraries that will do regular background work with some of the beans. However at applicationCreated we can't seem to find a way into the ServletContext via the ApplicationEx object. There are a lot of deprecated methods that appear they would have helped. Does anyone know how to traverse to the FacesContext or external ServletContext from ApplicationEx during the applicationCreated method?

Comment: I'd have to check to be sure, but given that each FacesContext instance is unique to a corresponding view instance, not to the whole application, there wouldn't be any direct link between the whole application and a single servlet within it... going in the other direction, of course, is trivial.

Comment: Thanks Tim, we would be interested to know if you find something. IBM does have FacesController in 8.5.3 which has a method getfacesContext but this has three Object params, and they have not documented anywhere in terms of what these Objects are meant to be.

Comment: The first parameter is a *HttpServletRequest*, the second a *HttpServletResponse* and the last one a *ServletContext*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the preload xpage feature ([bit.ly/10rfvEs](http://bit.ly/10rfvEs)) of the server but that does not create a session so there is never a FacesContext (get current instance returns null). So we did some tricks to open a link back to the app from the listener which then created the first session and app scope we needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, there is no way to get the FacesContext or ServletContext from ApplicationEx.

[ServletContextListener](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/) offers ServletContext when web application is initialized but, unfortunately, this kind of listener is not supported by XPages.

So, what about a combination of ApplicationListener and an application scoped managed bean ?

First, the ApplicationListener would start. Then the managed bean would be instantiated if it is "called" in beforePageLoad event of every page a user can call first. At this moment
the managed bean is able to get the ApplicationListener object with

```
(ApplicationEx)(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()).getApplicationListeners()
```

and can run a method in ApplicationListener to get FacesContext, ExternalContext and the bean. The ApplicationListener can start all actions (e.g. timer libraries) with the help of FacesContext/ExternalContext and save context and/or the bean as fields in ApplicationListener object. At applicationDestroyed() time it is still possible to work with context or to "shut down" the managed bean.

Here is an example:

ApplicationListener "MyApplicationListener"

```
package com.knutherrmann.listener;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationEx;
import com.ibm.xsp.application.events.ApplicationListener;

public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener {

    private FacesContext facesContext;
    private ExternalContext externalContext;
    private AppBean app;

    public void applicationCreated(ApplicationEx arg0) {
        System.out.println("applicationCreated(" + arg0.getApplicationId() + ") in MyApplicationListener");
    }

    public void applicationDestroyed(ApplicationEx arg0) {
        System.out.println("applicationDestroyed(" + arg0.getApplicationId() + ") in MyApplicationListener");
        System.out.println("...FacesContext: " + facesContext);
        System.out.println("...ExternalContext: " + externalContext);
        System.out.println("...AppBean: " + app);
        app.stop();
    }

    public void initContext(AppBean app) {
        facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        this.app = app;
        System.out.println("initContext() in MyApplicationListener");
        System.out.println("...FacesContext: " + facesContext);
        System.out.println("...ExternalContext: " + externalContext);
        System.out.println("...AppBean: " + app);
    }

}
```

Application scoped managed bean "app" as instance of class "AppBean"

```
package com.knutherrmann.listener;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationEx;
import com.ibm.xsp.application.events.ApplicationListener;

public class AppBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AppBean() {
        ApplicationEx app = (ApplicationEx) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
        for (ApplicationListener listener : app.getApplicationListeners()) {
            if (listener instanceof MyApplicationListener) {
                MyApplicationListener myApplicationListener = (MyApplicationListener) listener;
                myApplicationListener.initContext(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("AppBean stopped");
    }

}
```

XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    beforePageLoad="#{app.start}">
    Test MyApplicationListener and AppBean
</xp:view>
```

Server console's output

```
07:23:44   HTTP JVM: applicationCreated(32) in MyApplicationListener
07:23:44   HTTP JVM: initContext() in MyApplicationListener
07:23:44   HTTP JVM: ...FacesContext: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext@f850f85
07:23:44   HTTP JVM: ...ExternalContext: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoExternalContext@13891389
07:23:44   HTTP JVM: ...AppBean: com.knutherrmann.listener.AppBean@22c522c5

07:54:06   HTTP JVM: applicationDestroyed(32) in MyApplicationListener
07:54:06   HTTP JVM: ...FacesContext: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext@f850f85
07:54:06   HTTP JVM: ...ExternalContext: com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoExternalContext@13891389
07:54:06   HTTP JVM: ...AppBean: com.knutherrmann.listener.AppBean@22c522c5
07:54:06   HTTP JVM: AppBean stopped
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put that together. One technical point we left off is that we are actually using the ApplicationListener to create the app scope beans because some of the work is heavy lifting and taking time. We use the  preload xpage feature (http://bit.ly/10rfvEs) of the server but that does not create a session so there is never a FacesContext (get current instance returns null). So we did some tricks to open a link back to the app from the listener which then created the first session and app scope we needed.

Comment: I see. Your trick linking back to application is a nice workaround :)

Comment: @pipalia: You could use a Factory (http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1002) to preload your Data. I have not tested what happens if you preload the Database, but maybe this will work.

Comment: Thanks Sven - we will need to test it to see if this will preload Databases as well.

Comment: I tested Factory yesterday: unfortunately, "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()" in constructor "public HelloWorld()" returns null

Comment: Sure, FacesContext is null. But as far I unterstand the issue the FC is only required to instantiate some beans. And with the Factory you could use the bean as a "pipe" to the Factory only.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach thanks for the provided approach with the Factory! For sure smart approach! By the way: I am planning to hold MongoClient driver object in such factory and provide it to the whole XPages app. The Factory also has destroy() method which is to be called by    ApplicationListener.applicationDestroyed() method, implemented according to this blog post (http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=740). The most nicest thing here that the Factory is well accessed as from XPages as well out of the request / servlet context. Any suggestions on the reliability of such solution are highly appreciated! )